# how to get sub string after four spaces in the given string?

Tags: java

I have string like `"align is going to school sad may me"`. I want to get the sub string after the four spaces. The String will be entered at run time. can anyone suggest me to find the Sub String after some set of spaces......

```
String st = "align is going to school sad may me";

int i = 0;
String [] strings = new String [15];
StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer (st, " ");

while (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements ())
{
    strings [i]= (String)stringTokenizer.nextElement ();
    i++;
}
System.out.println ("I value is" + i);

for (int j=4; j<i; j++)
{
    System.out.print (strings[j] + " ");
}
```

I've tried this one and it's working can you please suggest me simple method to find the Sub string after some set of spaces.

Comment: 4 consecutive spaces or 4th space??

Comment: four spaces i.e String st= "I've tried this one and it's working can you please suggest " is the String and I want output as st="one and it's working can you please suggest" . That Sub string after 4th space.

Comment: @Ram - ... which is all after the **third** space. Confusion level slightly increased ;)

Answer (score 10):

```
st = st.replaceAll("^(\\S*\\s){4}", "");
```

`^` indicates that we remove only from the first character of the string.

`\s` is any white space. It would also remove, for example, tabulations.

`\S` is any non white space character.

`*` means any number of occurrences of the character.

So, `\S*` is any number of non white space characters before the white space.

`{4}` is obviously because you want to remove 4 white spaces.

You could also use:

```
st = st.replaceFirst("(\\S*\\s){4}", "");
```

which is the same but you don't need the  `^`.

In case the input string could have less than 4 white spaces:

```
st = st.replaceAll("^(\\S*\\s){1,4}", "");
```

would return you the last word of the string, only if the string doesn't end on a white space. You can be sure of that if you call `trim` first:

```
st = st.trim().replaceAll("^(\\S*\\s){1,4}", "");
```

Comment: Fixed the regex. Sorry I didn't remember to scape the backslash.

Comment: He doesn't want to remove four spaces. He wants the substring *after* the fourth space in the input.

Comment: @Andreas_D this removes both the spaces and the characteres between the removed spaces.

Comment: `"I've tried this one and it's working can you please suggest".replaceAll("^(.*\\s){4}", "");` gives `"suggest"` on my machine... (but, you're right, my previous comment was wrong)

Answer (score 5):

What about using split?

```
st.split (" ", 5) [4]
```

It splits string by spaces, into not more than 5 chunks.  Last chunk (with index 4) will contain everything after fourth space.

If it is not guaranteed that string contains 4 spaces, additional check is required:

```
String [] chunks = st.split (" ", 5);
String tail = chunks.length == 5 ? chunks [4] : null;
```

Tail will contain everything after fourth space or null, is there are less than four spaces in original string.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String st = "   align is going to school sad may me   ";
    String trim = st.trim(); // if given string have space before and after string.
    String[] splitted = trim.split("\\s+");// split the string into words.
    String substring = "";
    if (splitted.length >= 4) { // checks the condition
        for (int i = 4; i < splitted.length; i++)
            substring = substring + splitted[i] + " ";
    }
    System.out.println(substring);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MySplit {
    public static void main(String agsp[]) {
        String oldString = "roma h totti milan kaka juve love";
        String[] allStrings = oldString.split("\\s");
        String newString = "";
        for (int i = 3; i < allStrings.length; i++)
            newString = newString + " " + allStrings[i];
        System.out.println(newString);
    }
}
```

you can also make function like this

```
public String newSplit(String data, int index){
            String[] allStrings = data.split("\\s");
            String newString = "";
            for (int i = index; i < allStrings.length; i++)
                newString = newString + " " + allStrings[i];
            return newString
}
```

Comment: ... which is the fourth word in the string. Not the expected result.

Comment: @Andreas_D check my edit please, it works with me , what problems did you got from my code ?

Comment: The result is `h`. But the expected result is *everything after the fourth space*. But we want something so that `f("A B C D E F G H") = "E F G H"`

Answer (score 0):

This may be a overkill but it uses simple string operations  (`just str.indexOf(' ')`).
If you needed for a school project or someting:

```
String str ="ada adasd dasdsa d adasdad dasasd";

int targetMatch = 4;
int offset = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i < targetMatch; i++){
     int position = str.indexOf(' ', offset);
     if(position != -1){
          System.out.println("position: "+ position);
          offset = position+1;
        }
     }

String result = str.substring(offset);
System.out.println(result);
```

For real project... advanced regex would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trivial and simple implementation that solves your problem:

```
String s = "I've tried this one and it's working can you please suggest";

int index = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    index = s.indexOf(' ', index + 1);
}
System.out.println(s.substring(index + 1));
```

It will fail if the string starts with a space or if it contains sequences of spaces. But it's a start.

Output: `and it's working can you please suggest`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way using this piece of code

```
String thisString="Hello world go to kashmir";

String[] parts = theString.split(" ");
String first = parts[0];//"hello"
String second = parts[1];//"World"
String first = parts[3];//"hello"
String second = parts[4];//"World"
```